# Jquery still running the previous code and ignoring changes

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I have a `.js` file that whatever changes I do (I even delete all the codes) it doesn't recognize or run the new changes, it just run the last code I saved days ago.

Here is what I did before encountering this problem.

I made a copy of my project and save it in different folder(location) and now I deleted the original and used the copied one. I made some changes on the `.js` file but doesn't run the new changes. Anyone know the solution to this?

I tried cleaning and building the solution but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try cleaning the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a caching problem, did you try reloading without cache or doing a "hard reload"?
Open devtools (F12), right click the refresh button then press "Empty Cache and Hard Reload".

[image]